# Nodejs readable stream ignores highWaterMark for first chunk

Tags: node.js, stream

I've been reading from files using a highWaterMark that is 1/100 the size of the overall file - when using the default highWaterMark, sometimes chunks get lost as I upload the file chunk by chunk to a 3rd party service.

The problem is, the first chunk of every file uses the default highWaterMark of **65536**, which is almost always larger than the chunk size I would like. After this first chunk, the rest of the file is affected by the highWaterMark.

The highWaterMark is changed before I begin reading the file. I'm thinking maybe there is a race condition with the highWaterMark changing and the first chunk being read - maybe delaying the reading of the file would help enforce the highWaterMark for the first chunk. But reading files and uploading them is slow enough, and I would like to avoid extra performance costs if possible.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, or a potential solution?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: It's kind of complex. But a file is posted via a multipart form data request, and then converted to a readableStream with async-busboy.

After it's parsed, I change the highWaterMark and process the file. It's a bit difficult to display in snippets - but only the first chunk doesn't follow the highWaterMark, as I mention above.